# Algorithm for mapping users to a schedule based on time availability

Tags: algorithms

I have a project where I must map employees to a schedule. The basic concept is:

- Company Opens between 08:30 and 17:00.
- Employee 1 can work from 08:30 to 12:00 then from 13:00 to 1700;
- Employee 2 can work from 12:00 to 13:00.
- Employee 3 can work from 17:30 to 00:00

I would then want the employees mapped to the company object based on when they can work. So if I require one employee on at all times, in the example above Employee 1 and 2 would be working on that day.

I've got a couple of ideas in my head on how to approach this but wanted to check to see if there are any algorithms designed around this kind of task.

Comment: I recommend sharing what you have so far. That tends to be more productive: we can see what you have done and identify areas of improvement.

Comment: You are describing the [nurse scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurse_scheduling_problem) with a different set of constraints.  This is a rather well known (and difficult) problem.  There is an [entire industry](https://www.google.com/search?q=nurse+scheduling+software) around this problem.  Typically one uses a [rules engine](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html/useCasesAndExamples.html#d0e1555) and lets it do the work rather than trying to write it oneself.

Comment: @MichaelT - That's what I was after, could you mark it as the answer please. I thought there would be some general information about the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>This is written from the pragmatic point of view. Don't reinvent the wheel. You are better off learning and using a known piece of software than writing your own scheduling program that likely won't preform as well and will be 'fun' to maintain - both for you and the next guy.</sup>

Scheduling problems are hard... and not just hard, but they can often be NP-hard.  The problem described is a modification of the [nurse scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurse_scheduling_problem) which is a classic one that has been studied for several decades because of its difficulty.

If one wants to try to code it oneself, there are a number of techniques.  Those mentioned in the wikipedia article include decomposition, parallel computing, stochastic optimization, genetic algorithms, colony optimization, simulated annealing, Tabu search, and coordinated descent.

I should also point out that there is an *entire industry* of software programs around the nurse scheduling program.  A search for [nurse scheduling software](https://www.google.com/search?q=nurse+scheduling+software) turns up numerous results from different companies.

All of these fall into the area of [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming), and while one *could* sit down with prolog (or write your own), this tends to be the area where one would grab a rules engine appropriate to your platform and let it do the work.  One such example is that of drools, which has an example of [employe shift rostering](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html/useCasesAndExamples.html#d0e1555) using nurses (there are some other examples too including patient admission schedule, exam timetabling, and a traveling tournament problem).

Answer (score 2):

Brute force may not be feasible for even small datasets.

I have written something like this in my beginnings, in C#. I used a genetic algorithm.

The source code (hosted at [Codeplex](http://morawski.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Generator/Solving%20problem/GeneticOptimizer.cs)) is awful, I didn't know any better at the time. But you can take a look at the video presentation: http://vimeo.com/20610875

I start talking about the subject of your interest around 6:00.

Personally I got the idea from http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/carpalx/?simulated_annealing which is an interesting read. Nevermind the math, you can ignore it.

The solution yields really good results, as demonstrated in my video.